# I need help creating a good GIF

Tags: video-editor, video-quality

I am using VSDC to create a GIF image of three images that fade from one into the other.  I think I have gotten the fade working well.  In the timeline, I fade out one image as I also fade in the next one.  This works pretty well.

I made each image the same size and dimension. So this, I thought, would make it look smoother and the transitions look flawless.

The problem was not the images but the canvas.  I thought I was scaling the canvas/work site down to the size of the images.  But this is not the case since the resulting GIF has a huge black border.  Please advise.  I will probably have several follow-up questionis.